# Drag data from data base to a listbox

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, listbox, datasource

I want some data to be displayed in a listbox when the form is loaded. But after it is loaded nothing changes.

I added DataSource and used foreach to get the items.

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public CDiary diary;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        diary = new CDiary("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listOfEvents.DataSource = diary.Events;
        foreach(CEvent ev in diary.Events){
            listOfEvents.Items.Add(ev.Date);
        }
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you set the DataSource then do not try to add items one by one.

Comment: I tried using only DataSource without foreach and using foreach without DataSource and nothing changed.